# Is it possible to map manual copied files at Perforce?

Tags: perforce, configuration-management, p4v

I'm managing small team project with perforce.

We are now trying to merge our files, which we worked itselves.

But, our data is very large and network is very slow.

So, we want to copy files with HDD and copy to each other.

I'm wondering, if I merge our files with one WorkSpace and submit to Server, and copy with HDD to each other, then is it possible to mapping files which is copied to team member?

If it works, now we can work one stream.

When I try to copy and open P4V, it can't reconize it and try to download with network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this KB article on "cloning" clients: https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2446

You will need to use the command line, since this involves going a bit outside the normal Perforce workflow, but to reiterate what the KB article says:

1. Copy the files from the original workspace to the others.
2. `p4 flush`/`p4 sync -k` the other workspaces, using the original workspace as a revision specifier (e.g. `p4 sync -k @original_workspace`)

Note that if you do this incorrectly, the server will be confused about what's actually in your workspace, and life will be difficult (you may end up missing files without knowing it). If you're not positive that you got those two steps exactly right, use `p4 clean` to tell the server to check your workspace and re-sync anything that doesn't look right.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure about it, so I'll write scenario.

1. Copy my computer directory to HDD
2. Copy HDD to coworkers computer
3. In CMD, 'cd' to coworker's directory which is copied
4. p4 flush
5. p4 sync -k

Is it right? but what do you mean p4 sync -k @original_workspace?
You mean Depot or Stream name?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is where you're getting tripped up or not, but it's very important to understand that a "workspace" (or "client spec") is a thing that you define in Perforce that is tracked on the server; it's not *just* a local directory, and it's a completely separate concept from a depot or a stream (although a workspace can be associated with a stream, one stream may have many workspaces).  The KB article I linked might help -- it's hard to give a tutorial on Perforce in the 300 characters that SO allows for comments.  :)

Comment: I think, I do it. Thanks! You give me a great hint.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Samwise said about copying a workspace from one computer to another, you could look into running a Helix Proxy on one of the computers on your local network.
This way, the file data will only need to be downloaded from the main Helix Core server once and then will be stored locally on the Helix Proxy so it will be much faster for other users.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4dist/Content/P4Dist/chapter.proxy.html

Comment: Thanks but I think it doesn't need for me :)